# Flex error, unable to load SWC

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, swc

Need help in a very weird error in Flashbuilder where a SWC seems to magically appear and is giving me errors. All the updates to the SWC is not being recognised by Flashbuilder.

[image]

In my Libs folder, there is no ._controls.swc file in it but in the build path in Flashbuilder, it just magically appears and is giving me errors, which i suspect is what causing my original controls.swc to not be able to update its library of movieCLips in it.

Any idea what could have cause this?

Comment: Clearly you've selected _Remove_, but it comes back?  Is this a Flash Pro project being edited in Flash Builder?

Comment: This is a Actionscript project where the the art assets are exported from Flash Pro as SWCs. And I cant seems to remove that one individual SWC, I can only remove the whole SWC folder but when i added it back it, the ._controls.swc seems to reappear.

Comment: I would suggest re-creating a new project and adding everything from scratch

Comment: tried that.. didnt work too ..

Answer (score 1):

I just manage to get it working by removing the libs folder from my source and not from the flashbuilder. then creating a new folder and copy over the swc files into the new folder. then it works. so i guess there must have been some weird hidden file in the folder..

thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Had same issue. Ended up grabbing the source and referencing the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean your project go to Project>Clean, I think this may work for you!!

Comment: ya, clean the project but the error is still there.. this is really bugging me ..